# Excel VBA, Sort Dates via list

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to sort a list of Sales Orders (on a pivot table) and filter to find the entries that are scheduled to ship on a holiday (a list of ~12 dates).

Considering this pivot table is Dynamic, but the list of dates is not, is there a way to apply these filters via a VBA macro, so i do not have to do so manually?

I have tried using the Macro recorder, but it just sets all of the existing dates to

actual list came up much, much, larger

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesOrders").PivotFields("Due Date")
    .PivotItems("2/28/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("5/22/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("7/17/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("7/18/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/7/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/16/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/19/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/22/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/28/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/29/2019").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("8/30/2019").Visible = False
```

```
End With
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("SalesOrders").PivotFields("Due Date")
     .PivotItems("5/25/2020").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("7/3/2020").Visible = True
     .PivotItems("7/6/2020").Visible = True
End With
```

This doesn't really work, because the dates will change...
I'm not really sure how to progress, any help would be welcome.

Comment: aren't those items just text strings?  Seems you could build a collection of dates formatted as text, loop through the collection, and set the visibility as appropriate.  It might take 2 collections (loops), one that sets the visibility to False and the other that sets the visibility to True

Comment: Unfortunately, the dates are coming in date format via an external data connection...  is there a way to set visibility to false for all dates, then set it to true for only a few specific ones?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a new column to your data, you won't need to use VBA, you can get this incorporated in your pivot table. Add a new sheet that contains only the dates of the holidays in one column and True in the second column. Then add a new column to your Sales Order data and in that column use the Vlookup function to see if the date in your Sales Orders date is found in the list of holidays. You can add this new column to your pivot table as a filter. The screen shot below shows an example. 
[image: Vlookup Example]

Comment: Unfortunately, the data in my pivot table is coming in through an external data source which i had originally inputted straight to a pivot table.  Unless it is something that i can calculate in SQL (my data query), or create a calculated collum?

Comment: You could add the "Is_Holiday" column next to your pivot table and have its formula reference the dates in the pivot table. It will then point to the rows that are on holidays. I can't think of a way to allow you to filter the result but at least you could quickly scan the list for "TRUE" values. (You could use conditional formatting to make that scan easier.)